# Is it possible to mine 1 btc in one day?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, mining-reward, miner-configuration, hashpower

I am working in a company and my boss has ordered me to design a rig that can mine up to 1 BTC in a single day. I want to ask if is it possible. If it is then how much hash rate wil be required and what specs you guys recommend? Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are around 1000 btc minted daily and the global hashrate is around 400 Ehash/s so you need 1/1000 of that (400 Phash/s)